# TypeScript functional destructuring not enforcing default type

Tags: typescript

I have a function which accepts a single object parameter as follows. (Note, this is a contrived example but it demonstrates the problem.)

```
type FuncParams = { sayYes: boolean; }
type FuncType = (params: FuncParams) => string;

const maybeSayYes: FuncType = ({ sayYes }) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';

maybeSayYes({ sayYes: true }); // Returns 'Yes'
maybeSayYes({ sayYes: false }); // Returns 'No'
```

I want to make the `sayYes` property optional, so I updated the types as follows and added a default to the function declaration:

```
type FuncParams = { sayYes?: boolean; }
type FuncType = (params: FuncParams) => string;

const maybeSayYes: FuncType = ({ sayYes = true }) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';

maybeSayYes({ sayYes: true }); // Returns 'Yes'
maybeSayYes({ sayYes: false }); // Returns 'No'
maybeSayYes({}); // Returns 'Yes'
```

However, I noticed that I can assign any default value to `sayYes` and TypeScript doesn't flag up the incorrect type. For example:

```
const maybeSayYes: FuncType = ({ sayYes = 'notABoolean' }) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

I expected TypeScript to infer the `boolean` type from `FuncType` and stop me assigning a `string`, but it doesn't.

I can get the error to show if I explicitly type the parameter as follows:

```
const maybeSayYes: FuncType = ({ sayYes = 'notABoolean' }: FuncParams) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

However, I assumed TypeScript would infer this type from `FuncType`. I'm sure it's my understanding of TypeScript that's at fault, but I'd like to know:

1. Why TypeScript doesn't tell me that `'notABoolean'` isn't a `boolean`.
2. How I can constrain the default value type without having to duplicate the `FuncParams` typing.

[Reproduction on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYAUCGAnNBbAzlAXigG8pc0QBNCXAfgC4oAjAexYBsI0EBuKAXwBQoSLERIAKuGhEAFGEw5cjeMnRY8ASkIA%20MsAwBLBAHMegwQHpLUAMIsMGCEmBQAJhABmaOO1cA3NHY4aBEIQSQWBFxXbAomCABlCmpcAEYVcSlROVJyKhpCKAMQgW0CPXzUqFooAHJUuqhGOoA5FjrzKxsASWQHJxd3Lx8-KEDg0OkAGmY4V2ykpCMwVzcWGgQ610jsMHY0YwiomKg4kATkgtwAJkzkRaLZPJTCojqEFmAAQQAhNk43Ca-HKlVe%20FqDRoTRa7U6FmsUD6kUczjWI18ASCpTCs0WiWWhlWUAAIgB5ACiiSgu32hwQc1chlcTgAjnBDE58BAAB77QxIZnsEDFcDGEzFAAW0GMYHmUAUGigAHdmZKxGpFHhjtFYvEkuCAMz3STSJ4va5FD5fP4ArhbAQm9RKUFkcE1eqNZr1OE8IA)

Comment: This is weird behavior; not sure if it's been reported before.  The behavior is type safe (it's fine for function implementation to widen their parameter types), so it's not exactly *wrong*, but I don't see a use case for it.  Still looking

Comment: Okay, it's [microsoft/TypeScript#19127](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19127), this is working as intended.  I guess they want a union here because without it, `boolean` gets messed up (as it's represented as `true | false`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised by the behavior you describe, but my knowledge of TypeScript is still not very deep.

You can do it using a function overload type:

```typescript
type FuncParams = { sayYes?: boolean; }
type FuncType = {
    (params: FuncParams): string;
    (params: FuncParams & {sayYes: never}): string; // Or just: {params: {sayYes: never}: any;
};
```

Then, a call that tries to use `sayYes` with a non-`boolean` type will match the second overload and cause an error. *(Many thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for pointing out that `sayYes` can remain optional, and that you can use a simpler signature for he `never` overload.)*

That gives you this behavior:

```typescript
// Correct default value type
const maybeSayYes1: FuncType = ({ sayYes = true }) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';

// Incorrect default value type
const maybeSayYes2: FuncType = ({ sayYes = 'notABoolean' }) => sayYes ? 'Yes' : 'No';
//    ^−−−−−−−−−−−−− TypeScript compiler error here

// Correctly don't have it at all (since it's optional)
const maybeSayYes3: FuncType = ({ }) => Math.random() ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYAUCGAnNBbAzlAXigG8pc0QBNCXAfgC4oAjAexYBsI0EBuKAXwBQoSLERIAKuGhFigqAqgAKMJhy5G8ZOix4AlI1zAMASwQBzHvMUq1eTeJ3qoAMhLkqNRgggA3CBj8BmTGZpaCQoIA9FFQAMIsGBgQSMBQACYQAGZocOxpvmjscNAiEIJILAhGUNgUTBAAyhTUuACMDshSokRKpB6thFDGJQJ6hAB8ZC00ULRQAOStC1CMCwByLAtW0bEAksiJyakZ2bn5UIXFpdIVVTV1IA3NnrgATJ2S0kN9069DCwQLGAAEEAEJsTjcFZBSZ-QbzJY0FZrTbbXaKKAAPUASER4-EE-FQbpNJCmMBpSrYMAmTgYKABDCJKAACwC5QxCSSKWA7BAGSqCzSLLQ-igJjSaEl7HYylwZiQ0AlC3wLApJiqRT0d2qaUezxmuAAzJ8ST9SLCCFMALJSlkAOiwCHSLGwSnGiOWq0WaKsQA)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Although my minimal example only had one optional property, in reality I need multiple - is there any way to achieve this without a long list of overload types? I was hoping TS would interpret the fact that it's optional and essentially do this automatically.

Comment: @petewritescode - I bet it's possible with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and a generic type argument, but I don't immediately know how.

Comment: BTW, this behavior, while surprising to me too, is apparently working as intended as per [microsoft/TypeScript#19127](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19127).

Comment: I don't quite get why the overload fixes it; overloads tend to cause other problems, so it's up to OP to decide if this is worth it.  Anyway, I think you can keep `FuncParams` optional and just add the overload mentioning one of the optional properties and it will still work even if there are more optional properties.  Like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w18GOW).  But yeah, this whole thing is a weird one.

Comment: @jcalz Great find, I can understand the reasoning there even if it does seem a little counterintuitive.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because, although not as concise as I'd hoped, it does answer my question. In reality I find it too verbose to be used regularly so I'll stick with typing the parameters in the function declaration as per my example.

Comment: @petewritescode - It might be worth leaving the question in the "needs answer" list (by un-accepting this answer) in hopes that someone can come up iwith a better solution. If they don't, you can always re-accept later. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, thanks, I'm new here so wasn't sure what the etiquette was :) Thanks again!